# sed: remove strings between two patterns leaving the 2nd pattern intact (half inclusive)

Tags: regex, filter, sed, awk

I am trying to filter out text between two patterns, I've seen a dozen examples but didn't manage to get exactly what I want:

Sample input:

```
START LEAVEMEBE text
   data
START DELETEME text
   data
   more data
   even more
START LEAVEMEBE text
   data
   more data

START DELETEME text
   data
   more

SOMETHING that doesn't start with START
@ sometimes it starts with characters that needs to be escaped...
```

I want to stay with:

```
START LEAVEMEBE text
   data
START LEAVEMEBE text
   data
   more data


SOMETHING that doesn't start with START
@ sometimes it starts with characters that needs to be escaped...
```

I tried running sed with:

```
sed 's/^START DELETEME/,/^[^ ]/d'
```

And got an inclusive removal, I tried adding "exclusions" (not sure if I really understand this syntax well):

```
sed 's/^START DELETEME/,/^[^ ]/{/^[^ ]/!d}'
```

But my "START DELETEME" line is still there (yes, I can grep it out, but that's ugly :) and besides - it DOES remove the empty line in this sample as well and I'd like to leave empty lines if they are my end pattern intact )
I am wondering if there is a way to do it with a single sed command.
I have an awk script that does this well:

```
BEGIN { flag = 0 }
        {
                if ($0 ~ "^START DELETEME")
                        flag=1
                else if ($0 !~ "^ ")
                        flag=0

                if (flag != 1)
                        print $0
        }
```

But as you know "A is for awk which runs like a snail". It takes forever.

Thanks in advance.
Dave.

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop in sed:

```
sed -n '/^START DELETEME/{:l n; /^[ ]/bl};p' input
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a small syntax error with busybox sed (fixed now) - however: It doesn't seem to work when there are multiple "START DELETEME" one after the other (that is - when the next block that ends the ^[^ ] part begins, if it's another "START DELETEME" part - it will remain there... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/LEAVEMEBE/,/DELETEME/!d;{/DELETEME/d}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with awk:

```
awk '
/LEAVE|SOMETHING/{flag=1} 
/DELETE/{flag=0} 
flag' file
```

But if you still prefer sed, here's another way:

```
sed -n '
/LEAVE/,/DELETE/{
       /DELETE/b
        p
     }
' file
```